# SQL Server CASE WHEN and IN construction

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Having a problem with a WHERE search statement would like to use a construction like..

```
WHERE f.foo IN 
   CASE @bar
      WHEN 'BAR' THEN 
         ('FOO','BAR',BAZ')
      WHEN 'BAZ' THEN
         ('FOOBAR','FOOBAZ')
   END
```

or

```
WHERE CASE @bar
      WHEN 'BAR' THEN 
         f.foo IN ('FOO','BAR',BAZ')
      WHEN 'BAZ' THEN
         f.foo IN ('FOOBAR','FOOBAZ')
   END
```

where @bar is a well defined temp variable of the correct type and all that
f is defined nicely..

I get an error about "Error at ','

Comment: It isn't the lost ' that was my second rate typing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
WHERE (@bar = 'BAR' and f.foo IN ('FOO', 'BAR', 'BAZ')) OR
      (@bar = 'BAZ' and f.foo IN ('FOOBAR', 'FOOBAZ'))
```

Comment: I would favor this for maintenance sake. If there is another condition on when @bar = 'BAR' this is far more legible than the nesting that would result from the structure in the question.

Comment: I also would choose this over the next answer, I lean towards speed, but realize I will not see this code again in the maintenance cycle. 
Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    …
WHERE   @bar = 'BAR'
        AND foo IN ('FOO', 'BAR', 'BAZ')
UNION ALL        
SELECT  *
FROM    …
WHERE   @bar = 'BAZ'
        AND foo IN ('FOOBAR', 'FOOBAZ')
```

This will be most index efficient.

`SQL Server` will just optimize out one of the queries, depending on the value of `@bar`, and will use the index on `foo` to execute the remaining query.

**Update:**

Table `master` has `20,000,000` records with `2,000,000` records having `name = 't'`.

This query:

```
DECLARE @s INT
SET @s = 2
SELECT  *
FROM    master
WHERE   (@s = 1 AND name IN ('t')) OR
        (@s = 2 AND name IN ('zz'))
```

uses an `INDEX SCAN` and returns nothing in `4` seconds:

```
  |--Parallelism(Gather Streams)
       |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([test].[dbo].[master].[ix_name_desc]),  WHERE:([@s]=(1) AND [test].[dbo].[master].[name]='t' OR [@s]=(2) AND [test].[dbo].[master].[name]='zz'))
```

This query:

```
DECLARE @s INT
SET @s = 2
SELECT  *
FROM    master
WHERE   @s = 1 AND name IN ('t')
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    master
WHERE   @s = 2 AND name IN ('zz')
```

uses `CONCATENATION` of two separate queries (one of them being optimized out), and returns instantly:

```
  |--Concatenation
       |--Parallelism(Gather Streams)
       |    |--Filter(WHERE:(STARTUP EXPR([@s]=(1))))
       |         |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([test].[dbo].[master].[ix_name_desc]), SEEK:([test].[dbo].[master].[name]='t') ORDERED FORWARD)
       |--Filter(WHERE:(STARTUP EXPR([@s]=(2))))
            |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([test].[dbo].[master].[ix_name_desc]), SEEK:([test].[dbo].[master].[name]='zz') ORDERED FORWARD)
```

Comment: +1.  I hadn't considered using a UNION in this type of case.  I'll have to test this against using an OR condition to see which is more performant.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for building that test case.  You have just convinced me that I've been doing some things very very wrong. :)

Answer (score 2):

As a wild guess, could it be that you're missing a ' in this line:

```
f.foo IN ('FOO','BAR',BAZ')
```

it should be

```
f.foo IN ('FOO','BAR','BAZ')
```

Answer (score 2):

You might drop the case part of the query.  For Example:

```
WHERE ((@bar = 'BAR') AND (f.foo IN ('FOO','BAR','BAZ')))
OR ((@bar = 'BAZ') AND (f.foo in ('FOOBAR', 'FOOBAZ')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Case is an expression and not a statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE CASE @bar
      WHEN 'BAR' THEN 
         f.foo IN ('FOO','BAR','BAZ')
      WHEN 'BAZ' THEN
         f.foo IN ('FOOBAR','FOOBAZ')
   END
```

You missed a ' before BAZ

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can do such a construction, so you are stuck with something like:

```
where
  (@bar = 'BAR' and (f.foo = 'FOO' or f.foo = 'BAR' or f.foo = 'BAZ')) or
  (@bar = 'BAZ' and (f.foo = 'FOOBAR' or f.foo = 'FOOBAZ'))
```

or:

```
where @bar + '_' + f.foo in
  ('BAR_FOO', 'BAR_BAR', 'BAR_BAZ', 'BAZ_FOOBAR', 'BAZ_FOOBAZ')
```

Answer (score 0):

CASE statement only allows for scalar output. You might want to handle it this way

```
WHERE   CASE 
            WHEN @bar = 'BAR' AND @foo = 'FOO' THEN 1 
            WHEN @bar = 'BAR' AND @foo = 'BAR' THEN 1 
            WHEN @bar = 'BAR' AND @foo = 'BAZ' THEN 1 
            WHEN @bar = 'BAZ' AND @foo = 'FOOBAR' THEN 1
            WHEN @bar = 'BAZ' AND @foo = 'FOOBAZ' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END  = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something on this line:

```
WHERE (@bar='BAR' AND f.foo IN ('FOO','BAR','BAZ'))
    OR (@bar='BAZ' AND f.foo IN ('FOOBAR','FOOBAZ'))
```

It's also important that you understand why your snippets do not work (apart from mismatched quotes and other syntaxs errors). The CASE statement is not a control flow structure. It doesn't choose a branch of code and inserts it into your SQL. On the contrary, it evaluates its contents and returns a expression, just like a function call.